# Eigenvalues of element-wise ordered matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$ be two positive-definite matrices such that
$$a_{ij} \geq b_{ij} \text{ for all $i,j$ and for all $i$, } a_{ii} > b_{ii}\,.$$

That is, $A \geq B$ elementwise and the diagonals of $A$ are greater than the diagonals of $B$. In that case, can we say that $\lambda_{A,i} > \lambda_{B,i}$ for $i = 1, \dots, p$?

Intuitively, I think this should be true, but I am not able to show it mainly because I don't know if $A-B$ is positive definite.

Comment: Check [1, 2 ; 2, 1]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counter-example**:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 0\\
0 & 5
\end{pmatrix}\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}\phantom{+}4 & -3\\
-3 & \phantom{+}4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
**Addendum**: In case you are interested, it is worthwhile to point out that this disproves the claim in a slightly stronger setting since $A$ and $B$ are [Stieltjes matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_matrix) (a subset of the SPD matrices).